# Sublime Text: Can you disable autocompletion to words only appearing in comments?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext

For example, if I were to start typing "th" in the code below, it would suggest "This" and "this_is_a_function". Is it possible to make it never suggest "This" because that word only ever appears within a comment?

```
# This is a function
def this_is_a_function():
    pass
```

Obviously this is not a huge problem but it can still be annoying.

Comment: What IDE are you using?